# How to find out if a String contains a character and store values in 2 separate variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, substring

I am trying to seperate a `String` into 2 seperate `variables`. The `String` is stored in an array and contains a colon. I would like the value before the colon to be the first variable and the value after the colon to be the second variable.

I do not know how to do this: currently, I've gotten the following done, but it only uses the `substring` method.

```
for(i = 0; i< productArray.length; i ++){
    item = productArray[i];
    stockCode = item.toString().substring(0, 1)
    console.log(stockCode);
    quantity = item.toString().substring(3,5);
    console.log(quantity);
}
```

The array looks like this: `["EXCEL 5LB BLACK:2", "EXCEL 5LB BLACK:3", "SATO WHITE LABEL:2", "SATO INK PADS:1", "SATO GUN:2"]`

I'd like to store the values like this

- var1 = EXCEL 5LB BLACK
- var2 = 2

and so on

Comment: You should opt for the .split() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split() the string on the ':' with `split(':')`

```
for(i = 0; i< productArray.length; i ++){
    item = productArray[i];
    var parts = item.split(':');
    stockCode = parts[0];
    quantity = parts[1];
    console.log(stockCode);
    console.log(quantity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" ");
```

Results in `How,are,you,doing,today?`

Your case:

```
for(i = 0; i< productArray.length; i ++){
    var item = productArray[i];
    var split = str.split(":");
    var item_name = split[0];
    var item_val = split[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this maybe:

```
var str = "EXCEL 5LB BLACK:2";
var strArray[] = str.split(":");

strArray = [EXCEL 5LB BLACK, 2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `item.split(":")`. It will return an array containing the two values you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) each element of your array like this:

```
var newArray = [];
for(var key in productArray){//foreach element in array
   newArray.push(productArray[key].split(':')); //split by ":" and push into new newArray
}
console.log(newArray); //output could be [["EXCEL 5LB BLACK","2"],[...]]
```

Answer (score 0):

use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
for(var i = 0; i< ar.length; i ++){
    temp = ar[i].split(':');

    console.log('first='+temp[0]+' second='+temp[1])
}
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f9QeR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function.  It is used to divide a string by a delimiter to create an array of separate strings.

For instance:

> "comma,separated,values".split(","); // would produce: ["comma", "separated",
>   "values"]

Answer (score 0):

```
var productArray = ["EXCEL 5LB BLACK:2", "EXCEL 5LB BLACK:3", "SATO WHITE LABEL:2", "SATO INK PADS:1", "SATO GUN:2"];
var colorArray = new Array();
var numberArray = new Array();

for(i = 0; i< productArray.length; i ++){
    var item = productArray[i];
    var itemArray = [];
    itemArray = item.split(":")

    colorArray.push (itemArray[0]);
    numberArray.push (itemArray[1]);
```

}

```
console.log(colorArray);
console.log(numberArray);
```